# Heroku deployment on mac: Failed to build gem native extension, sqlite3.h missing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos, heroku, sqlite

I looked for a solution to my problem in some other questions, but even applying them to my case, I was not able to get heroku to work.
I'm following railstutorials.org and I receive the following log (with error) when calling

```
git push heroku master
```

I'm running my code on a Mac OS X 10.9.4 with MacPort, Brew installed, I uninstalled postgresql and reinstalled it and I've already updated Xcode command line tools and I just updated all the ruby libraries too.
What I get:

```
    -----> Ruby app detected
-----> Compiling Ruby/Rails
-----> Using Ruby version: ruby-2.0.0
-----> Installing dependencies using 1.6.3
       Running: bundle install --without development:test --path vendor/bundle --binstubs vendor/bundle/bin -j4 --deployment
       Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.........
       Installing i18n 0.6.11
       Installing rake 10.4.2
       Installing minitest 5.4.3
       Installing thread_safe 0.3.4
       Installing builder 3.2.2
       Installing erubis 2.7.0
       Installing rack 1.5.2
       Installing mime-types 2.4.3
       Installing coffee-script-source 1.8.0
       Installing execjs 2.2.2
       Installing thor 0.19.1
       Installing hike 1.2.3
       Installing multi_json 1.10.1
       Using bundler 1.6.3
       Installing tilt 1.4.1
       Installing sass 3.2.19
       Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
       /tmp/build_923c7430609effe5c7de55d5261b02b6/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/bin/ruby extconf.rb
       checking for sqlite3.h... no
       sqlite3.h is missing. Try 'port install sqlite3 +universal',
       'yum install sqlite-devel' or 'apt-get install libsqlite3-dev'
       and check your shared library search path (the
       location where your sqlite3 shared library is located).
       *** extconf.rb failed ***
       Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
       libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
       need configuration options.
...
Gem files will remain installed in /tmp/build_923c7430609effe5c7de55d5261b02b6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.10 for inspection.
       Results logged to /tmp/build_923c7430609effe5c7de55d5261b02b6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.10/ext/sqlite3/gem_make.out
       Installing json 1.8.1
       Installing arel 5.0.1.20140414130214
       An error occurred while installing sqlite3 (1.3.10), and Bundler cannot
       continue.
       Make sure that `gem install sqlite3 -v '1.3.10'` succeeds before bundling.
 !
 !     Failed to install gems via Bundler.
 !     
 !     Detected sqlite3 gem which is not supported on Heroku.
 !     https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/sqlite3
 !

 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app
```

What should I do to make heroku work with my code and libraries? 
Thank you in advance

Comment: You need to remove Sqlite from your gemfile

Answer (score 1):

Heroku recommends using Posgres in your gemfile.

Instead of `gem 'sqlite3'` use `gem 'pg'`.

Full instructions: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/sqlite3